# htaccess wildcard redirect (folder to subfolder)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing

.htaccess redirect entire directory to subfolder *(folders, subfolders and files to different subfolder)*

Trying to redirect `quarantine.country/coronavirus/svg` to `https://quarantine.country/coronavirus/images/svg` and while it works fine with the mentioned url (with or without the trailing slash /) it won't redirect https://quarantine.country/coronavirus/svg/coronavirus.svg

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^quarantine\.country$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.quarantine\.country$
RewriteRule ^coronavirus\/svg\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/quarantine\.country\/coronavirus\/images\/svg\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

*since this is a repeating mistake, please explain what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Another detail, the trailing "/": `/svg\/$1"` or `/svg$1"` -thank you!

Comment: What’s with all the escaping of the slashes? Not a single one of those should be necessary in the pattern, and inside the substitution, they might even mess things up. `RewriteRule ^coronavirus/svg/?(.*)$ https://quarantine.country/coronavirus/images/svg/$1 [R=301,L]` should work fine, according to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: (Be aware though that making the slash after `…/svg/?` optional, would make this match for URLs such as `/coronavirus/svgfoobar` as well. Depends on your setup, whether that might actually be a problem or not.)